# Common set rules and of allowed characters for filenames on Mac OS X, Windows and Linux in Qt

Tags: c++, regex, qt, cross-platform, filenames

In Qt, is there a method/Regexp for validating a filename that matches the file naming rules simultaneously for Windows and POSIX like filesystems?

It would split across

- forbidden characters (/:*?"<>|  +chars from 0 to 31)
- forbidden names (COM1, PRN, NUL.txt ...)
- forbidden sequences (filename ends with a space or a period)
- length constraint

There are already references about what's -not- allowed and -not- recommended

- https://serverfault.com/questions/150740/linux-windows-unix-file-names-which-characters-are-allowed-which-are-unesc
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#namespaces

but I would like to be sure to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Just an idea: what if you simply try to create a dummy file (temporary) with the given name and if it succeeds, the file name is ok?

Comment: @vahancho Because the fact that you can create a file with a given name doesn't mean that the name is OK.  I've had problems with this in the past: I created a name with a `':'` under Linux, and couldn't open the file (nor even delete it) under Windows.

Comment: @vahancho, James is right. It is all about creating a file on a system and be sure that its name is allowed on another system.

Answer (score 2):

The boost documentation "Path Name Portability Guide" at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/portability_guide.htm should give you an insight.
You might also get the source code and look into it.

Comment: I'm using Boost too so it could fit in my app as the implementation of `QValidator::validate()`. However, `portable_posix_name()` is too strong since, e.g., it forbids accented characters (like "é") while I can `touch` such filenames on my Linux box.